# How To Attach Floating Text to Game Objects when Destroyed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've attached the following script to a Game Object named "floatingText"

This works but I want to activate the floating text only when an object is destroyed.
I have another Destroy script attached to a sphere/bullet that is fired by pressing a button on screen to destroy a Cylinder object.

My question is how to get the floating text to show only when the Cylinder is destroyed by the bullet at the location of the impact.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Float : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Text text;
    public float fadeDuration = 2.0f;
    public float speed = 2.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        text = this.GetComponent<Text>();
        StartCoroutine(Fade());
    }

    public IEnumerator Fade ()
    {
        float fadespeed = (float)1.0 / fadeDuration;
        Color c = text.color;

        for (float t = 0.0f; t < 1.0f; t += Time.deltaTime * fadespeed)
        {
            c.a = Mathf.Lerp(1, 0, t);
            text.color = c;
            yield return true;
        }

        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        this.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);  
    }
}
```

The script that controls the destroying of the object:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Destroy : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public ParticleSystem effect;
    public AudioSource explosion;
    public Text scoreText;
    public GameObject floatingText; 

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
    {          
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Cylinder")
        { 
            effect.Play();
            explosion.Play();
            Destroy(col.gameObject);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the control Visible= true/false.

Comment: If you want to show only when the object is destroyed, then you need to show your code for when you activate the text, not the working portion.

Answer (score 2):

Simply disable the object in `Start` and enable it later:

```
public class Float : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Text text;
    public float fadeDuration = 2.0f;
    public float speed = 2.0f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        text = this.GetComponent<Text>();
        // Hide object
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    public ShowTextAndFade(Vector3 initialPosition)
    {
        StartCoroutine (Fade(initialPosition));
    }

    private IEnumerator Fade (Vector3 initialPosition)
    {
        // Show object
        gameObject.SetActive(true);

        // Set position
        transform.position = initialPosition;

        float fadespeed = (float)1.0 / fadeDuration;
        Color c = text.color;

        for (float t = 0.0f; t < 1.0f; t += Time.deltaTime * fadespeed)
        {
            c.a = Mathf.Lerp(1, 0, t);
            text.color = c;
            yield return true;
        }

        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        this.transform.Translate(Vector3.up * Time.deltaTime * speed);  
    }
}
```

and call it in the `Destroy` script. I asume you want to reuse that so I'ld use a prefab:

- Make the float object a prefab (drag it to the assets)
- remove it from the scene
- and reference the created prefab in `floatPrefab` of the `Destroy` component(s)

In `Destroy`:

```
// Reference the prefab in the inspector
public Float floatPrefab;

//...

effect.Play();
explosion.Play();
var position = col.transform.position;
Destroy(col.gameObject);

// Spawn the float text
var float = Instantiate(floatPrefab); 
// And start fading
float.ShowTextAndFade(position);
```

You can also skip the prefab part

- reference the actual object from your scene
- delete the `Instantiate` but instead use

  ```
  public Float float;

  //...
  float.ShowTextAndFade(position);
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The floating text should be made into a prefab so that it can be instantiated when the cylinder is destroyed using the `OnDestroy` event. Once instantiated, you can pass information from your cylinder to the instantiated floating text through the `floatingText` GameObject.

### Cylinder

```
...

public string textToShow = "Floating text you want to show";
public Vector3 pointOfCollision = gameObject.transform.position; // set on impact

void OnDestroy()
{
    GameObject floatingText = Instantiate(floatingTextPrefab, pointOfCollision, floatingTextPrefab.transform.localRotation);
    floatingText.Text.text = textToShow;

    StartCoroutine(floatingText.GetComponent<Float>().Fade());
}
```